# Google analytics script on dev site

Tags: google-analytics

I'm setting up google analytis on my webpage using the standard script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

If I include this site on my UAT page (e.g. http://uatsite.com/) will google track any activity or will it only track activity on my main site (e.g. http://production-site.com).

thxs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The domain (or, as GA likes to call it, *hostname*) from which Google Analytics receives its info doesn't matter and really it's up to the client to define it (and is very much exploited, see [this](http://blog.analytics-toolkit.com/2015/guide-referrer-spam-google-analytics/) for just one example).

If you don't want to track activity on your UAT site, you can create a `Hostname` filter to prevent the data from being recorded. This filter can be of **include** type so that only your production site registers or **exclude** type so it excludes only your UAT site.

Alternatively, you can modify your analytics code to not track on the UAT site:

```
if (!/uatsite/.test(window.location.hostname)) _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Yes... Here's an example describing the GA profile accidently being used on a different site and how use a custom filter to prevent the data from being record. http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/06/01/filter-by-hostname/

Comment: I dont think this is correct...according to the docs GA is only setup to track one domain by default: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: The Tracking Multiple Domains GA docs describe use cases for when you purposely and accurately want to track multiple domain and/or cross domain traffic. Mostly it's cookie related, like passing cookie data across domains, or setting the GA cookie domain name (with _setDomainName). Without any changes the default GA code will still record data from other domains but session tracking may be messed up.

Comment: It's easy enough to demonstrate: 
Go to your UAT site, and using the console in Chrome developer tools or Firebug enter the Javascript `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/test/test/test'])`.
Go to your analytics console and change the date range to today's date. Goto Content > Site Content > All Pages and search for "test".
It might not show up immediately, but you'll see a pageview for page '/test/test/test' show up within 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

This will only collect analytics for the url you configured. This will not collect from any other domain.